# Undocument 409 error using Square-Connect API

Tags: square-connect

I reran some test code that inserts several hundred items into my register.  The code worked a few months ago.  Now I'm receiving a 409 - "conflict/Another update may be in progress, please try again."

The error can happen when issuing a batch request of item DELETEs or batch request of item POSTs.  It does NOT happen when each delete or post is issued as an individual request.

My process runs synchronously under a single thread so I never have more than a single request into Square at any time.

I'm guessing that this is a bug that has been introduced as part of some code change to check for concurrent updates,  but which code has not been properly tested (again, just a guess).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out this undocumented error type. It is possible to receive a 409 error from items-related endpoints when you submit a large number of simultaneous requests (as with the Submit Batch endpoint). To reduce the likelihood of this error, you can reduce the number of requests you include in each individual batch (say from 30 to 15), or send each request individually.

Even after reducing the size of a batch, it is still possible that a 409 error might occur. Your application should be prepared to encounter this error and retry any affected requests.

If the issue persists, please add a comment to this question and we will investigate further.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code a solution based on your feedback.  Is there always a chance that a 409 can be thrown on an item in a batch add scenario even with only 15 items in the batch (i.e. does the probability go down but still exist?).

If there is always a chance,  then wouldn't there always be a need to deal with the possibility whether at a batch size of 15 or 30?  Should an add-item be retried on all 409-rejected items until they succeed?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've updated the answer to clarify that yes, this error can occur even with smaller batches. Your application should be prepared to retry requests that encounter a 409 error.

Comment: Does the idea that all of the developers using your api to add items in batch will have to code around this 409 error bother you at all?  Perhaps explaining the purpose of the 409 will help us understand the need for the defensive code that we will all have to write.  Thanks.